# Not showing ads after SKAdNetwork warn

Tags: admob, ads, skadnetwork

Hi my iOS app worked like a charm since 4 days ago when I start with admob till today I received a warning that tell:

"Some apps haven’t been configured to use SKAdNetwork"

After check my Info.plist it has the same updated version of SKAdNetworkItems that Admob recommend in help center.

I didn’t modify my code, it was working perfect and suddenly stop working and not showing ads.

Account active and running, no policy violation. All is fine.

I tried with TestAdsBanner and it works perfect.

Any help please??